# D3js path update enter and exit

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

What am I missing?
I am allowing users to remove and plot their own data point.  My line path is drawn with this and it works fine.

```
 let self = this;
        let line = D3['line']()
            .x(function (d) { return self.getColX(d.x); })
            .y(function (d) { return self.getRowY(d.y); });
        this.group = this.canvas.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(25,25)");

        //bind the data
        this.group.selectAll("path")
            .data(this.data[this.site].drawLine)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", line)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "black");

        this.group.selectAll('path').exit().remove()
```

My problem is, if I pop the last coordinates out and add a new one, call the draw function, the new points gets added correctly but the old points doesn't get remove.

For example:  my line goes from (x,y):  (1,3) to (3,6) to (7,8), if i remove (7,8) and replace that with 5,6.  i will see a new line from (3,6) to (5,6) but the line from (3,6) to (7,8) which is no longer in the data array still there.

Comment: Does this help you? https://bl.ocks.org/cmgiven/32d4c53f19aea6e528faf10bfe4f3da9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `enter()` and `exit()` selections are created after D3 compares your selection with the data provided. So they are available in the return of these calls:

```
this.group.selectAll("path")
            .data(this.data[this.site].drawLine)
```

And that's why new data is appended, `enter()` works just fine.

With `this.group.selectAll('path').exit().remove()` you create a new selection but is not comparing the selection against any data, therefore `enter()` and `exit()` selections aren't available to work with.

Long story short, just apply `.exit().remove()` to your initial selection and it should work. Something like this:

```
    let update = this.group.selectAll("path")
        .data(this.data[this.site].drawLine)

    update.enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", line)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "black")

    update.exit()
        .remove()
```

Comment: Your answer was going very well, but then you suddenly chained an `exit()` in an "enter' selection. Do you expect this to work?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado whoopsy daisy, thanks for the heads up

Comment: @GeradoFutado, do I break the change between stock and exit with ;?  is that what you mean?

Comment: @chungtinhlakho no, I was just addressing a previous code before the answer being edited. The answer is ok now.